# node.js ajax express show restful data on a web page

Tags: ajax, node.js, express, html

I am newbie in node.js development and I have a particular problem. I want to create a one page web app with node.js which will the user will submit request data and then gets data back from imdb api and will show them on the same page. My code is the following

**server.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.configure(function(){
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});

var fs = require('fs');
var inputFile = fs.readFileSync('index.html').toString();
console.log(inputFile);

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    response.send(inputFile);
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on " + port);
})




app.post('/', function(req, res){
if (req.body.mysearch == ""){
var search = "heroes";

}else{
    var search = req.body.mysearch;
}
    console.log(search);
    var http = require('http');
    http.get("http://www.imdbapi.com/?t=" + search, function(res) {
        console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
        var data = '';

        res.on('data', function (chunk){
        data += chunk;
})
res.on('end',function(){
    // the whole of webpage data has been collected. parsing time!
        var obj = JSON.parse(data);
        console.log( obj.Title );

   })
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
})
});
```

**index.html**

```
        <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Title of the document</title>
    </head>

        <body>
            <form id="myform" method="post" action="/"enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="text" id="search" name="mysearch">
<input type="submit" id="mysubmit" value="Search IMDB">
            </form>
            <div id="myTitle">
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

The code so far has successfully parsing the data from imdb and shows them on the console. The question is how I am going to print them on the web page (e.g on the div tag) without reload the page (ajax)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question regarding re-rendering of div that got answered

[how-to-re-render-html-div-in-node-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637701/how-to-re-render-html-div-in-node-js)

Basically solution was to use client side frameworks like [Angular.js](http://angularjs.org/) to help in re-rendering via 2 way data binding.